# How do i map http://localhost:8080 to http://mysites

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, localhost

I have a question identical to the one stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272542/how-do-i-map-http-localhost8080-to-http-mysites-in-iis7), but I still can't figure out how to make it work.

My situation is as follows (this is all BRAND NEW to me, so please forgive me if I use the wrong words to describe things, but I hope the overall description will still make sense):

- On IIS, I have a default ASP website that can be accessed by going to `http://MyHost/Site1`. This site is hosted on the default port for this host, which is port 80.
- I've created a new ASP website in IIS with a new AppPool, etc that is attached to port 8080 and is in a differnet folder on the local hard drive.

Now, I can access this website by navigating to `http://Myhost:8080`, but I would like to just be able to type in something along the lines of `http://MyHost/Site2`.

I am a total newbie to IIS, so please can someone offer me as clear a bit of guidance as possible?

Thanks SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IIS `Application` within the existing (default) website that maps to the other site.

The application name would be `MyTool2`, and its physical path would be the path to the other site.

Comment: thank you for the reply and it sounds like that could be what I need... I just have **NO CLUE** how to do that... Could you please elaborate some more / are there any links you could provide or even terms you could suggest I search for myself on Google to understand how to do this?? THANKS!!

Comment: @JohnBustos: Right-click the existing web site in IIS Manager, and click Create Application.

Comment: It doesn't work, I created a new application in the default website, but, for whatever reason, it doesn't connect to the DB, whereas when I do the EXACT same in a different website (and with a different port, then), it works perfectly! - I use the same apppool as for when it does work and everything... Any more thoughts about how I could fix this??

Comment: @JohnBustos: What exception do you get?

Comment: It's not an exception, it just doesnt connect to my SQLServer back-end and so the form doesn't populate while the other website (on port 8080... all else is the same) does

Comment: I **REALLY** do apologize if I'm not giving you enough information... Like I said this is all realyl brand new to me.... Thanks for helping!!