# how to simulate a cross origin site on local machine?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, simulate, cross-domain-policy

I am trying to simulate a cross origin site. Meaning I shouldn't be able to make ajax request from site A to site B since the browser will not naturally allow me to do so because of their cross-origin policy.

What are the tools I can use in this regard? Or are there any hacks?

What I've tried so far: I've opened a visual studio solution. It has two asp.net web form projects. One web project (say A) simply hosts a form with a file input control and a submit button. The other project B has a simple aspx page, which contains an iframe which loads site A inside of it.

I ran project B, and, in the browser console window, I did something like this:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('myiframe');
console.log(ifr.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
```

The console window displays the markup of site A's page which is loaded in the client's iframe.

Clearly I've failed. But is there I way I can do it on one machine.

Comment: check it out... http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Comment: @Jason how to simulate something similar to `http://otherdomain.com` on your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a bit of digging shows that you can achieve this feat is by modifying your hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) as mentioned in the post below:

[How do i map http://localhost:8080 to http://mysites in iis7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272542/how-do-i-map-http-localhost8080-to-http-mysites-in-iis7)